# Display enum property of model definitions

Tags: enums, swagger, swagger-ui

i am trying to display the enum of a model in the model description.
The schema of my model is defined under definitions and uses an enum for the action property, because only this three types are allowed. (see code below)

I am using swagger version 2.0. In version 1.2 this seems to work: http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/ you can find the example under store/order.
they also use an enum and this is displayed behind the property in the model view. 
How can i achieve the same result with the new version?

Thanks for help!

```
   "paths": {
    "/event": {
        "post": {
            "tags": [
                "event"
            ],
            "summary": "Add an new Event.",
            "description": "TEST",
            "operationId": "addEvent",
            "consumes": [
                "application/json"
            ],
            "produces": [
                "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "in": "body",
                    "name": "data",
                    "description": "",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Event"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "405": {
                    "description": "Invalid input"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
"definitions": {
    "Event": {
        "id": "eventModel",
        "required": [
            "action"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "action": {
                "type": "string",
                "default": "START",
                "enum": [ 
                    "START",
                    "UPDATE",
                    "END"
                ],
                "description": "blabla"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: another mistake i recognized right now, is that the shown model description of arrays misses the closing bracket ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is fine, there's a known bug in swagger-ui - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/672. Feel free to subscribe the issue and follow the progress there.

As a side note, there's no `"id"` property in models in Swagger 2.0.